# Filter/Sort with dynamic doctrine entity method in Sonata Admin list view

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I am trying to sort/search in a sonata admin list view based on a dynamic, non-database held value on a doctrine entity, however I can't seem to get this to work.

Ideally we can filter and sort by this dynamic value, however from this attempt (as below) it is unsortable and non-searchable:

```
//Entity
private $leadType;
public function getLeadType() {
    //Business logic to calc lead type
    $leadType = rand(0,50);
    return $leadType;
}

//EntityAdmin
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')          
        ->add('leadType');
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('leadType')
}
```

Comment: Have you found solution for this?